# How to open modal window by clicking on SVG element

Tags: svg, modal-dialog

I've got a complex SVG that is the floor plan of a building. I'd like to create modal windows or popups that provide a small description of the different rooms in the building.

The question: how do I add a boostrap modal (or other popup) on click of a  or  inside the SVG? I've tried adding the modal code within a  tag but that doesn't seem to be working.

```
     <rect   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#section-h-modal" id="section-h" x="112.6" y="31.4" class="mapsvg-region" width="35.2" height="69.3" style="vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke; fill: rgb(0, 125, 186);">
<foreignobject class="node" x="46" y="22" width="100" height="100">
<div id="section-h-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</foreignobject>
```

Comment: It's a local test site so I can't show it, but here some relevant code: added avove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used wrong tag to trigger the Modal Know more about 
                  foreignObject 
[Click Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject)
    
              and your solution is
        [here](http://codepen.io/manoj1991/pen/XMYEJX)

```
<svg>
 <g>
  <a xlink:href="#" class="btn-cta" >
   <rect   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#section-h-modal" id="section-h" 
    x="112.6" y="31.4" class="mapsvg-region" width="35.2" height="69.3" 
    style="vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke; fill: rgb(0, 125, 186);" >
   </rect>
  </a>
 </g>
</svg>
<div  class="overlay">
 <div class="modal">
 <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button class="close-btn">x</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-
       dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .btn-cta {
  width: 120px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  display: flex;
  margin-top: -10%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.59, -0.17, 0.3, 1.67);
}

.overlay.is-open {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.modal {
  transform: translate(0px, -50px);
  transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.59, -0.17, 0.3, 1.67);
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #231D23;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.modal .close-btn {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 3px 9px;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #9c9c9c;
  top: -1px;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(function () {
 $('.btn-cta').click(function () {
  $('.overlay').addClass('is-open');
  return false;
 });

 $('.close-btn').click(function () {
  $('.overlay').removeClass('is-open');
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In most libraries, e.g., bootstrap or materialize, you can open modal dialogs via JavaScript codes. For this reason, please read their examples to find out, how to open it.

To allow click events on your svg elements, you have to know, that each of the svg elements is an ordinary dom element. That means, you can access it like a `p` tag or something similar.

For example, you have a circle in your svg with id `circle01`. To add an on-click-event, you can use:

```
$("#circle01").click(function (e) { ... });
```

via jQuery or

```
document.getElementById("circle01").onclick = function (e) { ... };
```

via pure JavaScript.

To understand the magic of svg, you have to know, that it is pure html ;)